# wxPython dictionary of classes to events they call

Tags: python, class, dictionary, events, wxpython

I was wondering if there was a dictionary containing string versions of wxPython class (like 'Button' for wx.Button) to the events they call. This is what I want: `{'Button': wx.EVT_BUTTON, ...}`. Is there a dictionary like this anywhere in the module or on the web?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[wxGlade](http://wxglade.sourceforge.net/) knows about this: For every `Widget` there is a `class EditWidget` derived from `class ManagedBase` that has a class attribute `events` holding the names of the events sent by `Widget`:

e.g. in [widgets/bitmap_button/bitmap_button.py](http://bitbucket.org/agriggio/wxglade/src/tip/widgets/bitmap_button/bitmap_button.py) you'll find

```
class EditBitmapButton(ManagedBase):

    events = ['EVT_BUTTON']
```

You could collect the information you want by importing all these classes (can be done automatically, I think) and reading their `events` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I do (probably taken from the mailing list at some time):

```
for i in dir(wx):
    if i.startswith('EVT_'):
        print i
```

Clearly this isn't exactly what you're asking for, but the result is pretty intuitive to figure out what does what.

Answer (score 0):

To expound on what DrBloodmoney said:

```
adict = {}
for k,v in dir(wx):
    if k.startswith('EVT_'):
       adict[k[3:]] = v
```

However; beaware that although EVT_SOMETHING is an event class and is unique there is no guarentee that the Event object's ID number is unique (not to be confused with Python's id() built-in function).

Also when you, 'None', say: "I was wondering if there was a dictionary containing string versions of wxPython class (like 'Button' for wx.Button) to the events they call." I presume you mean "to the events the widget explicidly has event handlers too; event handlers being typically class methods like wx.Button.OnPaint()."

To find what event handlers any widget has, and when you don't use wxGlade for example, you can open each widgets Python module file. For example:

> \python\Lib\site-packages\wx-2.8-msw-unicode\wx\lib\buttons.py

Also remember while a wx widget might not handle an event type like wx.EVT_BUTTON, that doesn't mean it couldn't. And also that such a widget might pass some event types up to it's parent whether there's an event handler there or in it's parent; like a wx.Panel widget would.